# Store occurences of words in a file and their count,using Scanner.( Java )

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Here's the code:

```
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader ("C:\\mytext.txt"));
        HashMap<String, Integer> listOfWords = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        while(scan.hasNextLine())
        {
            Scanner innerScan = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());
            boolean wordExistence ;
            while(wordExistence = innerScan.hasNext())
            {
                String word = innerScan.next(); 
                int countWord = 0;
                if(!listOfWords.containsKey(word)){ already
                    listOfWords.put(word, 1); 
                }else{
                    countWord = listOfWords.get(word) + 1; 
                    listOfWords.remove(word);
                    listOfWords.put(word, countWord); 
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(listOfWords.toString());
```

The problem is, my output contains words like :

`document.Because=1`
`document.This=1`
`space.=1`

How do I handle this full stop's that are occuring?(And for further issues, I think any sentence terminator would be an issue, like question mark or exclamation mark).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the class notes for the [`Scanner API`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), in particular the paragraph on using delimiters other than whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

`Scanner` uses any whitespace as the default delimiter. You can call `useDelimiter()` of the Scanner instance and specify your own regexp to be used as delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your input to be split not only using white space delimiter, but also `.` and question/exclamation mark, you will have to define a [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and then apply it to your Scanner using `useDelimiter` ([doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29)).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to tinker with the following answer for speed optimization.

```
    final Pattern WORD = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
    while(scan.hasNextLine())
    {
        Scanner innerScan = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());
        while(innerScan.hasNext(WORD))
        {
            String word = innerScan.next(WORD); 
            if(!listOfWords.containsKey(word)){
                listOfWords.put(word, 1); 
            }else{
                int countWord = listOfWords.get(word) + 1; 
                //listOfWords.remove(word);
                listOfWords.put(word, countWord); 
            }
        }
    }
```